# Terraform : The "each" object does not support this operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create "Parent" and "Child" resources with Terraform, from a variable like this:

```
variable "tags" {
  default = {
    parent1 = ["child1", "child2"]
    parent2 = ["child2", "child4", "child5"]
  }
}
```

For each key in my variable I want to create a Parent resource, which I do and works fine:

```
resource "google_tags_tag_key" "parent" {
    for_each = toset(keys(var.tags))
    parent = "organizations/1234567890"
    short_name = each.key
    description = ""
}
```

My problem is regarding child resources ... For each item in a list, I want to create a child resource. But I can't seem to do a nested loop on the "for_each" argument.
So I tried to use the "setproduct" function to flatten my variable. as follows.

```
locals {
  helper_list = [for k, v in var.tags:
            setproduct(list(k), v)
      ]
}
```

This is a workaround, but despite everything, I still cannot resolve my problem by trying in the following way.

```
resource "google_tags_tag_value" "child" {
    for_each = local.helper_list
    parent = "tagKeys/${google_tags_tag_key.parent[each.0]}"
    short_name = each.1
    description = ""
}
```

This returns the folling error: `The "each" object does not support this operation`.
How can I solve my problem by going through a helper_list or without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

```
variable "tags" {
  default = {
    parent1 = ["child1", "child2"]
    parent2 = ["child2", "child4", "child5"]
  }
}

locals {

 # construct flat map
 helper_map = merge([
               for parent, children in var.tags:
                {
                  for child in children:
                  "${parent}-${child}" => {
                      "parent" = parent
                      "child" = child                      
                   }
                }
           ]...)

 
}

output "helper_map" {
  value = local.helper_map
}
```

which gives:

```
helper_map = {                                                                                                                                                                             
  "parent1-child1" = {                                                                                                                                                                     
    "child" = "child1"                                                                                                                                                                     
    "parent" = "parent1"                                                                                                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "parent1-child2" = {                                                                                                                                                                     
    "child" = "child2"  
    "parent" = "parent1"
  }                    
  "parent2-child2" = {  
    "child" = "child2"  
    "parent" = "parent2"
  }                    
  "parent2-child4" = { 
    "child" = "child4"  
    "parent" = "parent2"
  }                   
  "parent2-child5" = {
    "child" = "child5"  
    "parent" = "parent2"
  }
}
```

Then you can do, assuming I understand your desired outcome:

```
resource "google_tags_tag_value" "child" {
    for_each = local.helper_map
    parent = "tagKeys/${google_tags_tag_key.parent[each.value.parent]}"
    short_name = each.value.child
    description = ""
}
```